How to create a doubled bicolor wit a pareto frontier?
I have the following code that plots the results of two mathematical MILPS with different parameter combinations and determines the Pareto front based on the points. The code is:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
data = {
    'understaff1': [0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.3, 0.25],
    'viol1': [0.4, 0.35, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55],
    'omega1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'gamma1': [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
    'understaff2': [0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3],
    'viol2': [0.37, 0.4, 0.35, 0.45, 0.5],
    'omega2': [2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'gamma2': [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'understaff': data['understaff1'],
    'viol': data['viol1'],
    'omega': data['omega1'],
    'gamma': data['gamma1']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'understaff': data['understaff2'],
    'viol': data['viol2'],
    'omega': data['omega2'],
    'gamma': data['gamma2']
})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)


# Pareto-Frontier
def pareto_frontier(df):
    pareto_front = []
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        dominated = False
        for j, other in df.iterrows():
            if (other['understaff'] <= row['understaff'] and other['viol'] <= row['viol']) and (
                    other['understaff'] < row['understaff'] or other['viol'] < row['viol']):
                dominated = True
                break
        if not dominated:
            pareto_front.append(row)
    pareto_front_df = pd.DataFrame(pareto_front)
    pareto_front_df = pareto_front_df.sort_values(by=['understaff'])
    return pareto_front_df


pareto_df = pareto_frontier(df)

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
colors = plt.cm.tab20.colors

labels_dict = {}

# First Model
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    label = f"$\omega={row['omega']}, \gamma={row['gamma']}$"
    if label not in labels_dict:
        labels_dict[label] = plt.scatter(row['understaff'], row['viol'], color=colors[i % len(colors)], marker='o', s=100, label=label)
    else:
        plt.scatter(row['understaff'], row['viol'], color=colors[i % len(colors)], marker='o', s=100)

# Secon Model
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    label = f"$\omega={row['omega']}, \gamma={row['gamma']}$"
    if label not in labels_dict:
        labels_dict[label] = plt.scatter(row['understaff'], row['viol'], color=colors[i % len(colors)], marker='s', s=100, alpha=0.8, label=label)
    else:
        plt.scatter(row['understaff'], row['viol'], color=colors[i % len(colors)], marker='s', s=100, alpha=0.8)

# Pareto-optimal Points
for i, row in pareto_df.iterrows():
    index_in_df1 = df1[(df1['understaff'] == row['understaff']) &
                       (df1['viol'] == row['viol']) &
                       (df1['omega'] == row['omega']) &
                       (df1['gamma'] == row['gamma'])].index
    index_in_df2 = df2[(df2['understaff'] == row['understaff']) &
                       (df2['viol'] == row['viol']) &
                       (df2['omega'] == row['omega']) &
                       (df2['gamma'] == row['gamma'])].index

    if not index_in_df1.empty:
        color_index = index_in_df1[0] % len(colors)
        plt.scatter(row['understaff'], row['viol'], color=colors[color_index], edgecolors='black',
                    linewidths=2, alpha=0.6, s=150, marker='o')
    if not index_in_df2.empty:
        color_index = index_in_df2[0] % len(colors)
        plt.scatter(row['understaff'], row['viol'], color=colors[color_index], edgecolors='black',
                    linewidths=2, alpha=0.6, s=150, marker='s')

# Draw Pareto-Line
plt.plot(pareto_df['understaff'], pareto_df['viol'], linestyle='-', marker='x', color='red', alpha=0.7)

plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 0.5), ncol=1)

plt.xlabel('Scaled Understaffing')
plt.ylabel('Scaled Violation')
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

And this is the 
Please note that the different lists were chosen because the first lists (with 1 at the end) correspond to the results of model 1 and the lists with a 2 at the end correspond to the results of model two. Now I want to solve the model for different instances per parameter combination, and then display the results per parameter combination as a boxplot.  I would then display the data something like this.
'understaff1': [[0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.1], [0.15, 0.01] [0.3, 0.2], [0.33, 0.25]],
'viol1': [[0.22, 0.32], [0.12, 0.40], [0.31, 0.15] [0.23, 0.12], [0.34, 0.55]],
'omega1': [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2] [1, 3], [3, 1]],
'gamma1': [[0.22, 0.22], [0.02, 0.04], [0.4, 0.25] [0.31, 0.32], [0.34, 0.25]],
'understaff2': [[0.21, 0.12], [0.32, 0.13], [0.13, 0.4] [0.12, 0.23], [0.04, 0.35]],
'viol2': [[0.32, 0.14], [0.12, 0.12], [0.18, 0.15] [0.25, 0.04], [0.32, 0.15]],
'omega2': [[2, 2], [1, 0], [3, 4], [4, 0], [5, 3]],
'gamma2': [[0.2, 0.12], [0.22, 0.14], [0.1, 0.05] [0.35, 0.02], [0.3, 0.05]]

How do I get these double boxplots (one horizontally and one vertically) into a single plot to be created and the pareto frontier to be calculated based on the mean values of the respective boxplots of the respective parameter combination? This is what I mean by a double boxplot.
